# Why does `+[[]] + [[]]` return a string?

Tags: javascript

There is a statement `+[[]] + [[]]`. Console returns "0" (a string). 
When a statement is `+[[]]` console returns 0 (a number).
How come the first one returns a string if `+0+0` is 0?

Comment: The first one is a _unary_ plus, the second one a _binary_ one. Don’t confuse those.

Comment: javascript is weird. Would that answer your question? :)

Comment: @pro: where did the string come from?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax tree here looks like

```
            +
           / \
          /   \
         +   [   ]
         |     |
         |     |
       [   ]  [ ]
         |
         |
        [ ]
```

That is, the left hand side operand of the binary `+` is the result of the unary `+` operation, and the right-hand side operand is the result of the `[[]]` expression.

The left-hand side is a number, per the [runtime semantics of the unary `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) operator, which invokes [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber).

The right-hand side is an object, which is cast to a string primitive by [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) (by way of invoking the object's `toString` method) in step 9 of the [evaluation of the `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation). In the case of arrays, `toString` returns the stringified form of the array's contents joined by commas, which in this case is the empty string.

You can verify this by overriding `toString` on some object and seeing the changed result:

```
var a = [];
a.toString = function() { return "foo"; };
console.log(0 + a);
```

This will produce `"0foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

`+[[]]` - there is unary operator.

The Unary + operator converts its operand to Number type. The Unary - operator converts its operand to Number type, and then negates it.

Your expression is obviosly `+[[]]` plus `[[]]`
where '[[]]' are converted to an empty string due to binary `+` operator.

And therefore is `0 + '' = '0'`